# How to change discord guild bannner on another gif or image

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I change my guild banner, for example every 20 seconds? I need it for updating activity on my discord server right on the gif.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I want to share with you my recent problem with changing discord banner in real time.**

There is no much info so here it is.

> At first you need to **import**:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
```

> Then we create our **task**:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@tasks.loop(seconds=20.0)# sleep time of this func,
                         # and also makes this func as a task
async def set_banner():
    # iterate all connected guilds
    # can be simplified if your bot created only for 1 guild
    # guild = client.get_guild(your guild id as integer)
    for guild in client.guilds:
        guild = client.get_guild(guild.id)
        # we can't send image just as a gif file, so we need to transform it
        # into bytes with file.read() 
        with open("gif.gif", "rb") as file:
            banner = file.read()
        # and finally we change the banner
        await guild.edit(banner=banner)
         
if __name__ == "__main__":
    client.run("YOUR TOKEN")
```

> Then we need to start this task, we will do it in **on_ready()** event:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    set_banner.start()  # starts the loop of banner updating
```

**I wrote comments right in code, so I believe that you will understand**

And note that you must have 3'rd server level to change banner.

Comment: Changing the banner every 20 seconds might get you into a ratelimit at some point. Please also note that you need to reach a certain server level to be able to set a `GIF` as your server banner.

Comment: @Dominik 50 requests per second to discord API is global rate limit, I do not think that it could cause big problems. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, that's why I said “might”. One would need to check the headers, as this is not documented everywhere. Looping over all guilds, depending on how many, it can still happen though.